# JS: confirm() function take both answers OK and Cancel as true

Tags: javascript, confirm

I'm trying to use `confirm()` function in JS script to confirm important irrevercible actions that user do, such as deleting something by redirecting to corresponding link. But it doesn't matter what i click ok or cancel it takes it as true and redirect. Please help me to know what im doing wrong.

```
function confirm_boy() {
    if (confirm('are you really want to do what you are going to do?')) {
        redirect('http://example/?dosomething');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. You are missing `)` in `if` condition.

Comment: 1) you are missing `)` in ur `if` statement. 2) The code is working fine. It doesnot redirect on cancelling

Comment: i am very sorry for this misunderstanding, please don't beat me )) i will be using firebug in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close off the `if` condition properly

```
function confirm_boy() {
    if (confirm('are you really want to do what you are going to do?')) {
        redirect('http://example/?dosomething');
    }
}
```

Comment: just mistyped, sorry. edited

Comment: That is not a problem. Make use of debugging tools in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the if condition properly:

```js
if (confirm('are you really want to do what you are going to do?')) {
        console.log('ok')
}
else {
    console.log('no')
}
```